# Add list as a column to a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have the following lists:

```
cond_1 = [1,2]
cond_2 = [3,5]
```

And also the following dataframe `df`:

```
|----------|
| Column_1 |
|----------|
|     x    |
|----------|
|     y    |
|----------|
|     y    |
|----------|
|     x    |
|----------|
```

What I want to do, is to add a second column `Column_2`. following these criteria:

1) if `Column_1` contains a `x`, add a value in `Column_2` from `cond_1`;

2) if `Column_1` contains a `y`, add a value in `Column_2` from `cond_2`

The desired output should be like this:

```
|----------|----------|
| Column_1 | Column_2 |
|----------|----------|
|     x    |     1    |
|----------|----------|
|     y    |     3    |
|----------|----------|
|     y    |     5    |
|----------|----------|
|     x    |     2    |
|----------|----------|
```

I have been trying to do this using `pd.Series`:

```
df_x = df.loc[df['Column_1'] == "x"] #first I create a dataframe only with the x values
df_x['Column_2'] = pd.Series(cond_1)
```

Then I would repeat the same thing for the `y` values, obtaining `df_y`.

However, this doesn't succeed. Then, I would need to append again the two dataframes (`df_x` and `df_y`) and I lose information on the original index that I want to maintain from `df`.

Comment: Does the lists `cond_1` `cond_2` will always contains two elements?

Comment: Will you ever exhaust all elements, and if so what should happen to the third 'x' if you had 3 'x's?

Comment: No, in my file I have 5 lists, 4 of them containing 38 elements and the 5th only 36. And the number of xs will always match the number of elements in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a helper class and use it in an `.apply`, eg:

```
class ReplaceWithNext:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.lookup = {k: iter(v) for k, v in kwargs.items()}
    def __call__(self, value):
        return next(self.lookup[value])
```

Then use it as:

```
df['Column_2' ] = df['Column_1'].apply(ReplaceWithNext(x=cond_1, y=cond_2))
```

Which'll give you:

```
  Column_1  Column_2
0        x         1
1        y         3
2        y         5
3        x         2
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution with loop :

```
choice = ['x','y']
cond_1 = [1,2]
cond_2 = [3,5]
d = dict(zip(choice,np.vstack((cond_1,cond_2))))
#{'x': array([1, 2]), 'y': array([3, 5])}
```

---

```
for k,v in d.items():
    df.loc[df['Column_1'].eq(k),'Column2'] = v
print(df)
```

---

```
  Column_1  Column2
0        x      1.0
1        y      3.0
2        y      5.0
3        x      2.0
```

Comment: This solution changes the the Column 2 dtypes to from int to float. Do you have a more pythonic way of maintaining the int dtype than doing this after? df['Column_2'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Column_2'], downcast='integer')

Comment: @MatthewBorish `.astype(int)` afterwards may be why is assigning dtype later not pythonic?

Comment: Just wondering if you could maintain the int dtype in your for loop rather than adding an extra step at the end. I tried a few approaches unsuccessfully and thought you might have a solution.

Comment: In this solution directly assiging as integer might not be possible since when one condition sufficies column 2 is created with nans until the next loop runs and fills them. I am not sure this could be done inside the loop rather than doing it as a seperate step. But I might be wrong @Matthew

Comment: Good to know. Thanks for the explanation, anky_91. FWIW, with pandas 1.0.1 when Column 2 is included like this when building the inital df, your solution maintains the ints. df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_1':['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'], 'Column_2':['','','','']})

Answer (score 2):

You can `merge`. `pd.concat` will properly enumerate the index of each element of the lists. We'll need to `groupby` + `cumcount` the DataFrame to create this key there.

```
s = pd.concat([pd.Series(l).rename('Column_2') for l in [cond_1, cond_2]], 
              keys=['x', 'y'], names=['Column_1', 'N'])

df['N'] = df.groupby('Column_1').cumcount()
df = df.merge(s, on=['Column_1', 'N'], how='left').drop(columns='N')

  Column_1  Column_2
0        x         1
1        y         3
2        y         5
3        x         2
```

---

Using the `keys` and `names` arguments of `pd.concat` we can set up the merging Series which looks like below

```
print(s)
Column_1  N
x         0    1
          1    2
y         0    3
          1    5
Name: Column_2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Column_1':['x', 'y', 'y', 'x'], 'Column_2':['','','','']})

cond_1 = [1,2]
cond_2 = [3,5]

cond_1_idx = 0
cond_2_idx = 0

col_2_list = []
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    if df.at[idx ,'Column_1'] == 'x':

        col_2_list.append(cond_1[cond_1_idx])
        cond_1_idx +=1

    if df.at[idx ,'Column_1'] == 'y':

        print( df.at[0 ,'Column_1'])
        col_2_list.append(cond_2[cond_2_idx])
        cond_2_idx +=1

df['Column_2'] = col_2_list

    Column_1    Column_2
0   x   1
1   y   3
2   y   5
3   x   2
```